# Show only latest sms received from same number as Listview item in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am developing a sms application. When sms received it is saved in sqlite db and is shown in the listview as listview item. Now what the problem is that "If 4 messages are received from the number lets says "090071222" then each time sms is saved in database and it is shown as 4 separate items in the listview. I want to make that only one item similar to text messaging apps. In other way i want to save all these 4 items in database but only want to show the latest sms received from that number in the listview. Only the latest sms out of 4 messages is shown on listview and when i tap on the list item then it should show 4 messages inside it.

I am not putting any code here because it is simple that i saved every received sms in the database and then fetching it from that database in the listview. so i just need a hint or query that should be applied to only show the latest sms from that number. Any one please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only show one item per phone number in your listview, you can use `"GROUP BY phonenumber"` at the end of your sqlite query (where phonenumber is the name of the column you store the phone number in).

Then when you click on that one message, you can use `"WHERE phonenumber = ' + phonenumber + "' SORT BY date DESC"` in your query to sort the messages for that phone number by date, showing newest first.

If you had some code in your question, I could give you a better answer.

Comment: I got your answer somehow. but if i provide you some code in which i am saving received sms in database and fetching it then could you find the mistake in it and put query if so?

Comment: I ask the question again. This is the link for my question with all the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482559/group-by-query-showing-some-unexpected-results-in-list-view-android/38482718?noredirect=1#comment64367950_38482718