# Group by query showing some unexpected results in List view android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, group-by

I have a List view in which I am showing received messages from contact numbers. Now the problem was that if i received 5 messages from "1234567" and 3 messages from "56789" then my main listview was showing 8 messages although i just want to show 1 1 message by both these numbers in my main lisvtiew similar to sms apps as threads and on item click remaining messages should show for that particular number. 
Somebody answer me to use Group by phonenumber query to query the results by phone number.
When any sms received i saved it in table named as "smss".
This is my code when fetching data from database:

```
public ArrayList<Sms> fetchScreenedSms() {
  Sms a = new Sms();
ArrayList<Sms> smsInbox = new ArrayList<Sms>();
String query_fetchSMS = "select * from " + "smss" +  " group by " + "contactnumber" + "\"" ;
DBtableforNotSpam smsD = new DBtableforNotSpam(this);
SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsD.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = dbw.rawQuery(query_fetchSMS, null);
if (cursor != null) {
  cursor.moveToLast();
  if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

    do {

      Sms message = new Sms();
      message.id = cursor.getInt(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("id"));
      message.messageNumber = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("contactnumber"));
      message.messageSender = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("contactname"));
      message.messageContent = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("message"));
      message.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("date")));
      smsInbox.add(message);
    } while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
  } else {
     empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

this is my code for saving sms in database:

```
public void screenMessagee(Context context, String msg_from, String msgSender,
    String msgBody, String msgDate) {
    DBtableforNotSpam smsdb = new DBtableforNotSpam(context);
    SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsdb.getWritableDatabase();

    String query_insertSMS = "insert into " + "smss" + "(" + "contactnumber" + "," + "contactname" + "," + "message"
        + "," + "date" + ") values (\"" + msg_from.toString() + "\", \"" + msgSender + "\",\"" + msgBody
        + "\",\"" + msgDate + "\")";

    dbw.execSQL(query_insertSMS);
    smsdb.close();
    dbw.close();
    abortBroadcast();

  }
```

Now i applied group by query in fetchScreenSms method suggested by someone but if applied this then listview is showing nothing i.e. it empty listview data:

```
String query_fetchSMS = "select * from " + "smss" +  " group by " + "contactnumber" + " = \"" + "\"" ;
```

This is suggested by someone but it shows nothing in list view
and when i apply this then listview show data related to that number.

```
String query_fetchSMS = "select * from " + "smss" +  " group by " + "contactnumber" + " = \"" + "1234567" + "\"" ;
```

After this query, the listview show me one message from this number in my main listview and then 5 messages inside this. This is exactly what i wants. But why the upper query not working? I want to show both numbers messages

What and where is the problem occuring? 
Not showing results when using simple group by query but showing result when i specify number in group by.
Anyone please help Iam stuck

Comment: First, why do you use GROUP BY on the contact number ? This is probably an ORDER BY that you want. Also, you can't use a condition withGROUP BY, this is a syntax error (need to check with sqlite but SQL doesn't accept that).

Comment: PS : use PreparedStatement because I can send you and sms with SQL injection ;) and you insert will be more readable like this

Comment: @AxelH thankyou sir it worked you are a genious :)

Comment: What part, the order by ?

Comment: I tried to post an answer for this but I can't ... an XMLRequest error from the ajax... don't know if this is my enterprise that block this url or Stackoverflow having a issue...

Comment: @AxelH no worries sir it is solved thankyou for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have these troubles if you use [prepared statements](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). They are usually faster (if you need to do the same query multiple times), more robust and generally dont' lead to syntax errors that are hard to solve.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement( "insert into smss " +  
   "(contactnumbe,contactname,message,date)" +
   "values (?,?,?,?)";
```

See how much simpler it is? Then you can bind the parameters one by one. NO need to worry about escaping them properly. Prepared statements take care of that for you automatically.

```
  stmt.setInt(msg_from.toString());
```

and so on for each of the parameters. Getting to your GROUP by problem, I would try something like this:

```
"select contactnumber, contactname, count(*) from smss group by contactnumber" ;
```

Note that you can do SELECT * FROM smss, but the date and the messages columns are indeterminate because you are grouping by contact number. If there are multiple messages from that same number there is no assurance of which date and message will be shown. However that too can be controlled by clever use of sub queries and order by.

Comment: You are genious :) Thanks

Comment: oops @AxelH I came here from another question that the OP posted and I had the two questions mixed in my head when I answered this. Will update

Comment: @e4c5 Sorry, I removed the comment, I thought I made the same mistake because he accept your answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
"select * from " + "smss" +  " group by " + "contactnumber" + " = \"" + "\"" ;
```

This is not a valid SQL-Query
This Query would render to

```
"select * from smss group by contactnumber = "1234567"";
```

What's missing here is the "where" operator. Your query should include this and thus look like this:

```
"select * from smss where contactnumber = "1234567" OR contactnumber = "56789" group by contactnumber";
```

Or to display it like you did:

```
"select * from " + "smss" +  " where " + "contactnumber" + " = \"" + "1234567\"" + " OR " + "contactnumber" + " = \"" + "56789\"" + " group by " + "contactnumber";
```

Comment: Thankyou for correcting it Sir but i want to show messages from both these numbers. The last query you write just execute the results from "1234567" . I want to show message from "56789" too. What query should be used then?

Comment: You can append it with an `OR` operator. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I tried this sir but again the same result. My listview is showing nothing when applied this query

Comment: Answer is now updated, please check again. Doesn't it work like this?

Comment: I tried with this too but it wont showing anything. :( I think it should work but i am stuck.
As i said in my post that when i write "group by contactnumber" listview show nothing but when i write "group by contactnumber" = 1234567 then it show data related to it . Dont know whats the problem :(