# SQLite Exception near "from"

Tags: android, sqlite

I am just fetching data from my SQLite Database and it is saying that Syntax error near 'from' when compiling select from smss group by contactnumber. 
Here is my code:

```
 public ArrayList<Sms> fetchScreenedSms() {
ArrayList<Sms> smsInbox = new ArrayList<Sms>();
String query_fetchSMS = "select from smss" + " group by contactnumber " + "\"" ;
DBtableforNotSpam smsD = new DBtableforNotSpam(this);
SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsD.getWritableDatabase();
```

I tried with this too but it still says the same:

```
String query_fetchSMS = "select from " + "smss" + " group by contactnumber " + "\"" ;
```

Please Guide me whats the issue here

Comment: u haven't specified columns to fetch from Table. U can simply put * to get all columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify `columnName` or *(for all columns)

```
String query_fetchSMS = "select * from smss group by contactnumber";
```

Comment: why not simply `"select * from smss group by contactnumber"` since there is no variable here

Comment: I have given answer for OP's question only, not about coding structure or style

Comment: Silly Mistake, thankyou for helping I will mark the answer as correct after 5 mins

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: exactly, the query was incorrect, and still is ... the last char will result in an exception too because the SQL look like `select * from smss group by contactnumber"`.

Comment: @RRR can you help me in another problem? if you have spare time then i can give you a link for my question I am stuck there as well

Comment: @AxelH yeah, correct, will edit my answer, thank you

Answer (score 3):

because you have not specified the projection.  You need to give a list of fields to select, somethign like this

```
 String query_fetchSMS = 
   "select col1, col2, ... from smss group by contactnumber " ;
```

here is the full details of the select statement syntax:

https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/select-stmt.html

Comment: Hang on a second there is another syntax error "\"" would lead to unbalanced number of quotes

Comment: sir try a look at this question if you have little time. I am stuck here as well, here is a link for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482559/group-by-query-showing-some-unexpected-results-in-list-view-android/38482718?noredirect=1#comment64367950_38482718

Comment: Yes sir i corrected that one sorry to mention that here

Answer (score 3):

you missed * or column name in query

example query : `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME`(for getting all columns)
                          or

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLENAME (for single column)
```

so, your query will be

```
String query_fetchSMS = "select * from " + "smss" + " group by contactnumber " + "\"" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the "*" before "from"..OR you can specifie a column name to retrieve data from table.